# How to know preferred icon size for MenuItem?

Tags: android, icons, menuitem

I my application I have one large PNG file containg hi-res image. Depending on situation I would like to use this image either as icon or as placeholder for `ImageView`.

For MenuItem this image is too large, so I need to scale-down it to suitable size. I mean if it has to be displayed on large enough device like Samsung Galaxy Tab - I need to use one scale, for in small ones another, etc. I just noticed that for small-sized devices MenuItem icon is not scaled just cut - which is ugly.

So the question is how should detect which is preferred size?